# ServiceStack: ConfigurationManager does not exist?

Tags: c#, servicestack, configurationmanager

Using the newest version from servicestack github I am trying to run the project solution ServiceStack.AndroidIndie
However upon trying to build this solution I get the following error:

> Error  1   The type or namespace name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in  > the namespace 'System.Configuration' (are you missing an
>   assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\m41n\Documents\GitHub\ServiceStack.Text\src\ServiceStack.Text\LicenseUtils.cs  106 55  ServiceStack.Text.AndroidIndie

I tried using the v3 source code aswell without luck..

Any ideas what I might have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(are you missing an assembly reference?)`.
The error clearly says that the reference to the `System.Configuration` is missing. Add `System.Configuration` reference to your project.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/860240/1665670

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Bharadwaj

Under references, there is no tab named ".Net", and not in any tab  is there "System.Configuration".

However, I browsed through my system for System.Configuration.dll and manually added it. Is this acceptable??

Comment: Yes. If that dll is fully functional (doesn't depends on other supposting dlls), then it will do its work for you.